# SQL problem with error "Invalid data type"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Using SQL 2008

So I created a User Defined type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ServiceType AS TABLE (
[TO_ZONE] varchar(30) NOT NULL,
[FROM_ZONE] varchar(30) NOT NULL,
[RATE] decimal(14,2) NOT NULL,
[SERVICE_TYPE] varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

And when I try to use it I get the error "parameter or variable @variableName has an invalid data type"

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ImportServiceTypeRates]

(@ServiceTypes dbo.ServiceType)  --I have tried it without the "dbo." as well
```

**Update**

So I added "READONLY" to my variable declaration

```
@ServiceTypes dbo.ServiceType READONLY
```

And I now get the error "The parameter @Servicetype cannot be declared READONLY because it is not a table-valued parameter"  ?WHAT?

I thought the "CREATE TYPE ServiceType as TABLE" was what declared it such???

I also have showing in Types\User-Defined Table Types\dbo.ServiceType

Comment: Where do you declare @variableName?

Comment: @Nishant SQL server 2008

Comment: @astander the (@ServiceTypes dbo.ServiceType READONLY)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must declare your table-valued parameter as `READONLY`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ImportServiceTypeRates]    
   @ServiceTypes dbo.ServiceType READONLY 
AS
   --your proc
```

Even though SQL Server forces your table-valued parameter to be read-only, you must also explicitly declare it so in the stored procedure parameter list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

Comment: Ok, once i have I get the error that I can't set it as READONLY because @ServiceTypes is not a table-valued parameter  I'll update my question.

Comment: @pghtech: is that a runtime error, or is that SSMS with a red squiggly and the hover tooltip with that error? I've repro'd in my test environment exactly as you'd have it, and I indeed see the same error, only in the tooltip. When executing the `ALTER` query, it executes fine with no problems.

Comment: To future readers: to fix the red squiggly in SSMS, I had to exit and re-open SSMS after creating the type. Not sure why, but the query editor wouldn't recognize the type no matter what otherwise.

Answer (score 147):

I know this is an old post but since I encountered the same issue and was able to solve it, thought of sharing it. This is an IntelliSense cache issue and could be solved by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (shortcut for Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache)

Comment: this should be marked as the right anwser; it worked like a charm for me. Tks a lot

Comment: That problem was driving me crazy, and this answer was the one that helped me out :) Thanks!

Comment: oh, man, how long I've wished I had known this shortcut. Wish I could upvote this more

Comment: If you're working in SSMS, you can do this by toggling IntelliSense off and on at `Query -> IntelliSense Enabled`

Comment: Worked! Thank you.

Comment: I spent several hours to find out that this problem is caused by intellisence cache issue, wow. This should be marked as the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 9):

As long as you do not declare any parameters other than the table type in the stored procedure, you will get the red squiggly line error in Intellisense, but the stored procedure should be created or altered successfully.  This appears to be an unfixed Microsoft bug.

Comment: +1 However I still see the red squiggly after adding a second parameter of type `int`.  Infact, red squigglies are everywhere in my procedure's body.  The query executes just fine though, so good enough for now.

Comment: This bug is still in effect in SQL Server 2017, shows red squggle, mouse-over shows an error like OP was describing, but the command runs fine.

Thanks!